# Is there a getattr or a property getter for userdata

Tags: lua, lua-5.2

I am trying to get a property of a userdata object. Similair to `getattr` in many other languages.

Say for variable `obj` which is a userdata object I want to get a property, but that property is in a variable `someVar`.  Meaning I can't use `obj[someVar]` I'd have to use something like `getattr(obj, someVar)`.

Is there a way to do this in Lua?

Comment: You can use `obj[someVar]` if you define an index metamethod for `obj`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't the one who made the library

Comment: Without an `__index` metamethod, userdatas don't have any properties at all. `getattr` would be useless in Lua, because you can always use brackets to access an arbitrary key, without using a literal.

Comment: From lua reference manual: Userdata has no predefined operations in Lua, except assignment and identity test.